# ArcGIS TIN from Raster error message Arcpy

Tags: runtime-error, raster, arcgis, arcpy, traceback

I am trying to create a TIN from a Raster (.tif) in ArcGIS Pro with the following code

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
env.workspace = "C:\\Uni"
arcpy.RasterTin_3d("dgm1_05314000_Bonn.tif", "C:\\Uni\\Outputs Karten\\TIN_BN", "2", "1000", "1")
```

as per https://desktop.arcgis.com/de/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/raster-to-tin.htm documentation. However, the following error message occurs and I'm not able to decipher the problem. I'm not a regular GIS or python user and need to create this TIN for my thesis, so apologies for the blunt lack of knowledge.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ddd.py", line 4180, in RasterTin
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ddd.py", line 4177, in RasterTin
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.RasterTin_3d(*gp_fixargs((in_raster, out_tin, z_tolerance, max_points, z_factor), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 050045: Failed to add Raster domain
Failed to execute (RasterTin).
```

Can somebody explain to me how this can be solved?